# How do I prevent Lists returned from a JPA Repository having null values

Tags: java, list, jpa

I have parent-child object model where `Category` has a list of `Product`s. This is biderectional, the `Product` has a `parentCategory` property.

This is modelled as a `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` JPA Mapping.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id private String id;

    private String displayName;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "parentCategory",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @OrderColumn(name = "seqNo")
    private List<Product> products;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String displayName;
    
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Category parentCategory;

    @JsonIgnore
    private int seqNo;
}
```

Because the order of products is important, and I want the user to manually reorder them, I have added a `seqNo` property/column and have specified the `@OrderColumn`.

When moving products up or down, I do

```
Collections.swap(products, index, index + 1);
```

or

```
Collections.swap(products, index, index - 1);
```

as required, and then `repository.save(category)`

The `Product` List gats saved with `seqNo` in the correct order, but often (but not always) there are gaps in the sequence, giving rise to `null` elements in the list.

Likewise, when assigning a new `Category` to a `Product`, I do

```
oldParentCategory.getProducts().remove(product);
newParentCategory.addProduct(product); // this sets parentCategory on Product as well as adds Product to Category's products List
categoryRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(new Category[]{oldParentCategory, newParentCategory}));
```

This also leaves a gap in the old `Category`'s sequence numbers.

What am I doing wrong? and how do I fix it?

(**P.S.**: My JPA implementation is Hibernate [via Spring Boot]. My database is file-based H2 with a pretty basic setup [in development], if that's relevant)

Comment: You have two fields trying to control the value put in the "seqNo" column. If you want to manually control the column, you should be using @OrderBy on the OneToMany so that it uses those values - it is then up to you to set them in the Product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking my cue from @Chris (https://stackoverflow.com/users/496099/chris), I made sure that my `seqNo` values were always reconciled before saving, with

```
public void reconcileSequenceNumbers() {
        products.stream().forEach(p -> {
            int oldSeqNo = p.getSeqNo();
            int newSeqNo = products.indexOf(p);

            if (newSeqNo != oldSeqNo) {
                p.setSeqNo(newSeqNo);
            }
        });
    }
```